# java compile error due to directory same name as file

Tags: java, import, compilation

Heey everyone,

I am trying to compile a class file but because there are some directories which contain a file "a.java" but also a directory called "a", errors

```
com\ImmutableProjectImportController.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
/*  22:    */ import com.h.a.h.a.at;
                            ^
  symbol:   class h
  location: class a
```

When I remove the file h.java in the folder a, then there is no error on that line.

Are there arguments to the javac.exe to solve this?

```
javac -classpath blub.jar com\gui\exportimport\assignmentlistimport\ImmutableProjectImportController.java
```

Files without the dull imports work without problem.

Comment: For the sake of the programmer who has to maintain this code one day, use more descriptive package and class names. At least capitalize the first letter of class names.

Comment: haha i know but this aint my own code... and there are 100s of folders with a single letter aswell as files with a single letter in all the folders.

Comment: So you ARE the programmer who has to maintain this code. My condolences to you sir.

Comment: Decompiling code from someone else is not, @4castle, a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

You're wrong:

```
$ mkdir a
$ printf "package a;\npublic class a {\npublic static void main(String[] argv) {\nSystem.out.println(\"we're here\");\n}\n}" > a/a.java
$ javac -s a a/a.java
$ java -cp . a.a
we're here
```

At a guess you're trying to decompile an APK and, while it gives you an idea it never works perfectly.  Let us know more about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi there. Why don't you rename the class? Also, the use of lowercase filenames/classes is discouraged in Java.